# Dynamic tooltip in continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

The problem is I have a continuous form and there's a column that the tooltip is not the same for every rows.

For example:

The users are used to refer regions as a number, so I would display to number and I would display the complete name in the tooltip. That way I save space and there's no scrollbar.

What I did is put an hidden field with the tooltip value then in my current form event I have

```
txtRegionID.controltipText = hiddenRegionName
```

As I thought, the tooltip is set to the first value for every rows.

I guess it's not possible cause a continuous form is like a single form so it's always the same control and you can't change it's properties depending of the records.

Am I right? Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: The control tip will be set to what ever works for the current row, which is a problem, because ControltipText is a hover effect. You could use StatusBarText, which only activates for the current row.

Comment: I don't understand the control tip problem. What's the difference with the statusBarText?

Comment: A control tip works when you hover over the relevant control, no matter which row it is on, so it will show an inappropriate tip for any row except the current one, whereas the StatusBarText only activates when you click a row, so you are always on the row it applies to.

Comment: I see. So there's no way I can do this with a tooltip. Thank you, can you write this as an answer plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the illustration below, row 3 is selected and row 1 has a hover that shows Tip Three, which is wrong for row 1, but right for row 3. The status bar text shows Tip Three, which is the right tip for the row. The status bar will only show when a row is selected.

[image: Control Tips]

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.ID.ControlTipText = Me.Tip
    Me.ID.StatusBarText = Me.Tip
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the tooltip code from [Stephen Lebans website](http://www.lebans.com/tooltip.htm) - it allows you to have the tooltip display the current value in a continuous form (among other things).

It may not work under newer versions of Access - 2007+. The author also has retired from things Access, so don't look for support there.